# System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I just need to create a simple login page using SQL Server Express and keep getting the error this is my code.

I have tried multiple connection strings my database is name work

This is the full error I get:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

My code:

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Web;  
using System.Web.UI;  
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MechWorks.Account
{
    public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void ButLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Work;Integrated Security=True;");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from test where cUsername=@username and cPassword=@word", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UserTxt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("word", PasTxt.Text);

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            con.Open();
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                 Session["id"] = UserTxt.Text;
                 Response.Redirect("Redirectform.aspx");
                 Session.RemoveAll();
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "You're username and word is incorrect";
                Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error seems pretty clear to me. The server is not running or not listening or not reachable. Almost certainly you are not using the right instance name. You should start there, by verifying the instance you are using is correct.

Comment: Try validating your sql server credentials using the SSMS, i am sure you are providing something wrong to the connection string.